# when a picture is taken twice and display image in imageview, app crashes

Tags: android, out-of-memory

the first time, there is no problem and it works fine. But when I hit the "take picture" again, then the app crashes. Here is my code:

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivReturnPic);
Bitmap = bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
myImage.setImageDrawable(bmap);
```

Here is the logcat information:

```
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:650)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:389)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:449)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at com.example.customcalenderandroid.Camera.onActivityResult(Camera.java:232)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3178)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3225)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1275)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
08-09 10:06:23.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28492):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 10:06:23.840: E/android.os.Debug(2401): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: If this is easily reproducable, then add a delay between the takes of the pictures, for example 5 seconds and then see if it occurs again. I suppose, that this tries to override the same file and tries to visualize an unfinished file.

Comment: thanks, how do you add a delay? can you give me the code ?

Comment: try to clear your ImageView by calling myImage.setImageDrawable(null); before applying the next picture

Comment: In addition to Maver1ck's advice, I'd recycle the bitmap explicitly afterwards.

Comment: thank you this fixed it: if (myBitmap!=null){myBitmap.recycle();myImage.setImageDrawable(null);}

Answer (score 1):

The Exception you are getting is an OutOfMemoryException. This means, as the name implies, that your app ran out of memory. Handling images in Android can be a little bit tricky sometimes, especially when you take full size pictures. Not many smartphones, even high end ones, can handle more than one full size bitmap being loaded at the same time. Recycling not needed bitmaps as soon as possible with bitmap.recycle() can solve a lot of problems. Here you can find more information on loading bitmaps in a memory-friendly way:
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskScalePhoto